# Header + Video slider are bigger than the screen

Tags: css, header

would appreciate your input on this. Im quite new to CSS, so can't figure out where I've gone wrong with this.

Here's the link to the website: https://test.irinamccann.com

The problem is this: either the top-header, or video containers are bigger than the screen. The rest of the content is fine though.

First noticed on older Firefox, now I see that when you scroll the site to the side, there's a big white section on the right hand side.

Just don't know where it's coming from???

Custom CSS thats been added, that might be causing the issue (??)

```
.site-brand-inner {
position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%;
display: table;
}

.site-logo {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align:center;
}

#masthead {line-height:89px
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `.site-brand-inner` div has width 100% with absolute position. So it's width will be that of screen but as it has some left margin it will need space in right side and that makes it scrollable to right.

Remove the width 100% in your index page at line number 168 you'll be good to go.

```
.site-brand-inner {
 position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%; //remove this width
 display: table;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! It looks like it's fixed now?? Im really trying to learn CSS as we speak, could you please, send me to some explanation why 100% width could cause this? Thanks so so much!

Comment: Hi. What happens is 100% width makes the div to be as wide as size of your screen. For example of your screen width is 1366px, 100% width will make your div to be 1366px wide. It's okay if your div start from left most side, but what if there is something in left that won't let the div start from the parent left?  The div will have to shift eight to complete it's width. So that make it scrollable.     Please upload and mark correct if works. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks so much for taking time explaining this to me. Totally makes sense.